# Short Circuit EXISTS statment in SQL Server query for Table Valued Parameters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization, where-clause, table-valued-parameters

I use stored procedures:

In my WHERE clause, I use short circuits (OR's) to speed up execution as the Query Optimiser knows that most of my inputs are defaulted to Null. This allows my query to be flexible and fast.

I have added a Table Valued Parameter to the WHERE clause. The execution time for a report has risen from 150ms to 450ms, reads from 70,000 to 200,000.

```
...
WHERE
    --Integer value parameters
    AND ((@hID is Null) OR (h.ID = @hID))
    AND ((@dID is Null) OR (d.ID = @dID))
    AND ((@mID is NULL) OR (m.ID = @mID))
    --New table value parameter 
    --Execute, Processing time and read's increased. 
    --No additional JOIN added.
    AND (NOT EXISTS (SELECT Null FROM @rIDs) OR r.ID IN (SELECT r FROM @rIDs))
```

How can I short circuit the NOT EXISTS or speed up this query please? I have tried adding a BIT value and checking if rows are in the Table Valued Parameter before executing the query. The only way I have found is having two queries and executing one over the other. Not great if I have to modify a whole bunch of queries or add multiple Table Valued Parameters to the mix.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

A comparison of table value parameter:

```
    AND (NOT EXISTS (SELECT Null FROM @rIDs) OR r.ID IN (SELECT r FROM @rIDs))
```

and integer parameter:

```
    AND ((@rID) OR (r.ID = @rID))
```

showed similar execution speed after compilation with TVP at 0 rows and Integer parameter null. I assume the Query Optimiser is short circuiting in the correct manor and my previous comparison was incorrect. Execution plan splits the above cost at 55% vs 45%, which is acceptable. Although the split doesn't change when there are more rows in the TVP, the time to generate the report increases because more pages have to be read from disk. Interesting.

Comment: Have you tried `option ( recompile )` to check the performance without caching the execution plan?

Comment: I tried OPTION (RECOMPILE), query time increased two fold. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
if exists (select * from @rIDs)
    begin
    .... -- query with TVP
    end
else
    begin
    .... -- query without TVP
    end
```

This allows a separate execution plan for each query.

Comment: I mentioned this approach in my question, but I have a large number of variables & queries to consider. I may have to use this approach if I can't find a suitable solution for my query.

Comment: You could try `option (recompile)`, which would force a compilation for every query execution.  The query plan will then be estimated using the actual rowcounts.  Given the run times in your question, this can certainly pay off, as a typical recompile costs just 20ms.

Comment: Thanks Andomar, the explanation of the option(recompile) option is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using a table variable. If you use a temporary table and index the column you are using for your criteria (r in your example), you will avoid a table scan. This however makes it a multiple step process, but they payoff can be huge.

To be more specific to your question, you can change the last line of your example to be
    AND EXISTS (SELECT r FROM @rIDs WHERE r = r.ID AND NOT r IS NULL)

If you could post the execution plan, I could give you a much better answer. Click the Display Estimated Execution Plan, right click the execution plan and select Save Execution Plan As...

Comment: I would say `the payoff *can* be huge` rather than make a blanket statement that implies this is the way it should always be done. Also the syntax you posted is not correct: `AND EXISTS r.ID IN ...`?

Comment: Hi John, I could add an index to the table, my problem is if the TVP has zero rows, then I'd expect the index scan to be irrelevant.  I also tried the EXISTS r.ID IN but it complained about syntax, is that a 2012 feature?

Comment: Sorry about that to both you and Aaron. I edited my answer above. Made a mistake on my copy paste. Did you get a chance to look at the execution plan?

Answer (score 0):

You could try a LEFT JOIN between your table to be queried (on the left) and your TVP.